# Hide a commandLink onClick

Tags: visualforce, javascript, style, commandlink

I'm trying to hide a commandLink type"button" onClick, i will give you the code below.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
applyCSS: function(cmp, event) {
        var cmpTarget = cmp.find('save');
        $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'changeMe');
        }
<script/>
```

css:

```
changeMe {
            visibility: hidden;
            }
```

client-side:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
                        <apex:commandLink id="save" action="{!onSave}" value="Save" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false};" styleClass="btn slds-button slds-button_neutral" rendered="{!AND(selectedPB != null, OrderAccount.Enqix_Dead_Live__c != 'Dead')}" />
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!onCancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_neutral" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Comment: You're working in Visualforce here. You can't use Lightning controller-style JavaScript methods or access component API. The `$A` Lightning API object is not available.

Comment: I notice that this is your fifth question, and you have yet to accept an answer on any of them. Upvoting and accepting answers is, of course, optional; however, doing so helps out the community in several ways: - The person whose answer you upvote or accept is granted reputation points - You gain reputation points for accepting an answer - Upvoting answers helps other people determine how likely it is that a given answer is correct or may apply to them - Accepting answers signals to people that new answers are no longer required, and one has helped you out the most.

Comment: @Derek F you are right sorry i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in your CSS, `changeMe` should be `.changeMe`. However, that's not necessary, because you can just use `slds-hide` (assuming you use `lightningStylesheets="true"`), which does the work for you. Second, you can't use Lightning-style JS outside of Lightning, so `cmp.find(...)`, nor `$A.util.addClass(...)`. Third, you never actually called applyCSS, so it wouldn't work anyways. In Visualforce, you'd just do this:

```
<apex:page ... lightningStylesheets="true">
<script>
function applyCSS() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="save"]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link) {
    link.classList.add('slds-hide');
  });
}
...
<apex:commandLink id="save" action="{!onSave}" value="Save" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false} else { applyCSS() };" styleClass="btn slds-button slds-button_neutral" rendered="{!AND(selectedPB != null, OrderAccount.Enqix_Dead_Live__c != 'Dead')}" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, that did the trick.